# F#: if-else as an expression (returning values)?

Tags: if-statement, f#, immutability, multiple-value

Suppose I'm trying to write a clone of the `xxd` command in F#.  It has two operation modes;  one to convert a binary file into a hex dump, and another (selected by `-r`) to convert the hex dump back into a binary file.

Some languages allow me to write something like this:

```
let (inputFile, isReverse) = if args.[0] == "-r" then
    (args.[1], true)
else
    (args.[0], false)
...
if false == isReverse then
    forwardMode inputFile
else
    reverseMode inputFile
```

But this doesn't seem to compile under F#.  Are there any idiomatic ways to write this in F#?  I'm not a great fan of `ref` or `mutable`, though I know I would be able to write something like this with them:

```
let isReverse = ref false
let fileName = ref args.[0]
if !args.[0] == "-r" then
    isReverse := true
    fileName := args.[1]
...
if false == !isReverse then
    forwardMode !inputFile
else
    reverseMode !inputFile
```

Note: I'm not interested in nice command line parser libraries which I might or might not get with `nuget`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fine F#

```
let (inputFile, isReverse) = 
    if args.[0] = "-r" then
        (args.[1], true)
    else
        (args.[0], false)
...
if false = isReverse then
    forwardMode inputFile
else
    reverseMode inputFile
```

Two changes: indent the `if` and replace `==` with `=`

Comment: Oops, `==` was just a typo (I write C++ for my day job.)  I can never get accustomed to the offside rule... Perhaps I should have listened to `fsharpc` more carefully.